# does JavaFX css have a way to stop background color getting over the border edges?

Tags: css, javafx, styling, user-experience

I'm trying to make a card like the bootstrap CSS, but using JavaFX components. I want a rounded border but the background color of the top part (the header) is giving me problems.

The background overflows the border and looks quite ugly. I've googled a bit and found that an overflow:hidden on the background color should solve it. JavaFX css doesn't seem to have that though. Is there another way of solving this?

My solution so far:

[image: card]

Comment: The way to do what you want (as far as I can guess) is to specify the clip property which cannot be done from CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intro), overflow is not supported.

> JavaFX CSS does not support CSS layout properties such as *float*, *position*, *overflow*, and *width*. However, the CSS *padding* and *margins* properties are supported on some JavaFX scene graph objects. All other aspects of layout are handled programmatically in JavaFX code. In addition, CSS support for HTML-specific elements such as Tables are not supported since there is no equivalent construct in JavaFX.

However, to solve the rounded-background issue you can use `-fx-background-radius` along with `-fx-border-radius`. They should be the same value. You can find it [here in the reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

---

Here's an example of a bootstrap-like card that I think you are trying to make. You would use `-fx-background-radius: <top-left> <top-right> <bottom-right> <bottom-left>;` which would be `-fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;`

[image: Example]

```
public class Card extends StackPane {
    public BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    public StackPane header = new StackPane(), content = new StackPane();
    public Card() {
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().add(border);
        border.setTop(header);
        border.setCenter(content);
        border.setStyle("-fx-border-color: cornflowerblue; -fx-border-radius: 10; ");
        header.setStyle("-fx-background-color: derive(cornflowerblue, 70%); -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0; ");
        header.setMinWidth(100);
        header.setMinHeight(80);
        content.setMinWidth(100);
        content.setMinHeight(100);
    }

    public BorderPane getCard() {
        return border;
    }

    public StackPane getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public StackPane getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Card card = new Card();
    card.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setVgap(10); grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.addRow(0, new Label("Username"), new TextField());
    grid.addRow(1, new Label("Password"), new PasswordField());
    grid.addRow(2, new Button("Submit"));
    card.getContent().getChildren().add(grid);

    Label title = new Label("Card Example");
    title.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD, 36));
    card.getHeader().getChildren().add(title);

    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    stack.getChildren().add(card);

    Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 500, 300);
    stage.setTitle("Boostrap-like Card Example");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Guess I should've cleared my question more clearly, because this doesn't actually solve the problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I've added an example and screenshot to hopefully show what I meant. The background overflow is what you are having an issue with right? Since you don't have `overflow: hidden` like in natural css you have to combine `-fx-border-radius` with `-fx-background-radius`.

Comment: @James_D I posted that comment before Matthew edit'ed his answer. Thank you Matthew, I can't believe I've looked over that tag... I still can't think of a good title though.

Comment: @user3470438 you mean question title? I came here searching for exactly this so I guess it's not that bad :)